# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory exhausted

Tags: php, memory, phpexcel

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)`

For work I have to convert and reformat several xls and xlsx files to csv. Since I'm lazy and don't actually own a copy of Excel I wrote a few lines using PHPExcel which loops through a directory on my hard drive, converts each file and saves it to another directory.

The script works great, saves me loads of time, but if there are more than 4 or so files to be converted I get the memory error.

Is there a way to clear data from memory after it's no longer needed? As you can see below, I tried doing a bunch of unsets but it didn't seem to help.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
set_time_limit(0);
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'helper.php';

function swapExt($file, $ext){ return str_replace(substr($file,strpos($file,".")),".".$ext,$file);}
function makeCSV($table){$csv = ""; foreach($table as $r){$csv .= implode(",", $r).",\n";}return $csv;}

$filesDir = dirname(__FILE__)."\\files";
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($filesDir);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {

        $xlsfile = $filesDir."\\".$fileinfo->getFilename();

        $csv_filename = dirname(__FILE__)."\converted\\".basename(swapExt($xlsfile,"csv"));

        $fd = fopen ($csv_filename, "w");
        if (!file_exists($xlsfile)) {
            exit($xlsfile.": File doesn't exist.\n");
        }
        $arrxls = excelToArray($xlsfile, true);
        $rearr = array();
        $cell_int = 0;
        $row_int = 0;
        foreach($arrxls as $row_arr){
            foreach($row_arr as $k=>$v){

                //add lastname to new array
                if(strpos($k, "LASTNAME") !== false){
                    $rearr[$row_int][0] = $v;
                }
                //add firstname to array
                if(strpos($k, "FIRSTNAME") !== false){
                    $rearr[$row_int][1] = $v;
                }
                // add mi to array
                if(strpos($k, "MIDDLENAME") !== false){
                    if(strlen($v) > 1){
                        $rearr[$row_int][2] = substr($v,0,1);   
                    }else{
                        $rearr[$row_int][2] = $v;
                    }
                }
                //add address line 1
                if(strpos($k, "ADDRESSLINE1") !== false){
                    $rearr[$row_int][3] = $v;
                }
                //add address line 2
                if(strpos($k, "ADDRESSLINE2") !== false){
                    $rearr[$row_int][4] = $v;
                }
                //add city
                if(strpos($k, "CITY") !== false){
                    $rearr[$row_int][5] = $v;
                }
                //state
                if(strpos($k, "STATE") !== false){
                    $rearr[$row_int][6] = $v;
                }
                //zip
                if(strpos($k, "ZIPCODE") !== false){
                    if(strlen($v) > 5){
                        //if it's longer than 5 chars, set first 5
                        $rearr[$row_int][7] = substr($v,0,5);
                        $rearr[$row_int][8] = substr($v,-4);
                    }else{
                        $rearr[$row_int][7] = $v;
                    }
                }

                $cell_int++;
            }
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][0])){$rearr[$row_int][0] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][1])){$rearr[$row_int][1] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][2])){$rearr[$row_int][2] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][3])){$rearr[$row_int][3] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][4])){$rearr[$row_int][4] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][5])){$rearr[$row_int][5] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][6])){$rearr[$row_int][6] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][7])){$rearr[$row_int][7] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][8])){$rearr[$row_int][8] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][9])){$rearr[$row_int][9] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][10])){$rearr[$row_int][10] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][11])){$rearr[$row_int][11] = "";}
            if(!isset($rearr[$row_int][12])){$rearr[$row_int][12] = "";}    
            $row_int++;
        }
        $fileContent = makeCSV($rearr);
        if(fputs($fd, $fileContent)){echo $xlsfile." converted.<br />";}
        fclose($fd); 

        unset($fd); unset($fileContent); unset($rearr); unset($arrxls);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't read the entirety of each csv into memory using `$arrxls = excelToArray($xlsfile, true);`... read and process a row at a time so you only ever have one row in memory at a time

Comment: how would i do that? could you post an example as an answer?

Comment: Not really, because I can't see the code for excelToArray() or for makeCSV() both of which would need changing to work line by line